# Any way to exclude accounts from mail indicator?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, thunderbird, mail

I only want one of my accounts to make the mail indicator go blue when I get a new message, but I don't want it monitoring the second account I also have in Thunderbird. Possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any settings to customize the *Message Indicator* behaviour.
By the way, as a workaround, you could disable the "*Check for new messages on startup*" and the "*Check new messages every...*" in Thunderbird account settings for the second account you don't want the icon to get blue.

To access these two options, `click Edit -> User Accounts` in TB, then select the `Server Settings` tab for the account you want to disable.

If you do this, just remember sometimes to manually download messages for the second account.